# OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '' urls.py:

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms

I am trying to do the following:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from OnlineShop import views

urlpatterns= [
    path('OnlineShop/',include('OlineShop.url')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and I get the following error:

> OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label
>   syntax is incorrect: '' urls.py:

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use `r'path'` instead of `'path'` on the line that causes the error.

Reason is given here: [WinError 123 The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63868961/winerror-123-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is-incorrect)