# WinError 123 The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mask

[WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

[image]

Comment: Try using two backslash, instead of one in your file path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in the path `\f` is decoded as ascii formfeed `\x0c`, hence the issue.
Use `r` in front of path as `r"c:\\path\to\dir"` to make it raw string.

Comment: Should I leave as follows: 
imgs = list(sorted(os.listdir(r "C:\\Users\cjarq\Desktop\Cagebot\kaggle\input\face-mask-detection\images")))

len(imgs)

Comment: There is a space between `r` and `"`. Remove the space and use it.