# Python converting folder name from 1-Sample to x01-Sample

Tags: python, shutil

I am having python code that check directories for .pdf file. On Windows system the folder name is
1-Sample, while code execution the folder name is converted to x01-Sample and getting below error.

Error : [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Actual Path - D:\1-Sample
While code execution the path is treated as - D:\x01-Sample

```
    for filename in os.listdir(sourcePath): #sourcePath = D:\1-Sample
        if not filename.endswith(".pdf"):
            if os.path.isfile(sourcePath+filename):
                #create directory if doesn't exists.
                if not os.path.exists(othersDocumentPath):
                    os.makedirs(othersDocumentPath)
                shutil.move(sourcePath+filename, othersDocumentPath+filename)
```

Could anyone please help me how to resolve this issue, it should read the actual folder name which is
1-Sample.

FULL STACK TRACE

[WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'D:\x01-Sample'Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Pyhton/Projects/Sample/main.py", line 20, in get_pdf_searchable_pages
for filename in os.listdir(sourcePath):
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'D:\x01-Sample'

Comment: Please add the entire stacktrace.

Comment: I suggest using `os.path.join` instead of string addition.

Comment: I found answer in below thread, however wanted to understand why it is converting folder name with digit to hex.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63868961/winerror-123-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is-incorrect